# Variable in class not updating when changing value

Tags: class, flutter, dart, constructor

I  have a variable named `number` and a class which sets a variable to `number` in its constructor. I then change the value of `number` but the `number` in the class doesn't update. Here's my code:

```
void fn1() {
  int number = 5;
  SomeClass someClass = SomeClass(number);
  // Do some other things which take a long time
  number = 2;
  someClass.printer(); // prints 5. expect 2
}

class SomeClass {
  int nestedNum;

  SomeClass(this.nestedNum) {
    printer();
  }

  void printer() {
    print(nestedNum);
  }
}
```

How can I get `nestedNum` to update anytime `number` is changed?

So the hacky/easy solution would be anytime I change `number` in `fn1`, I need change `nestedNum` in `someClass`: like this: `someClass.nestedNum = 2`. The issue with that is if I have multiple classes I would have to go through each one to change the variable.

Another solution I thought of, was to never pass `number` into `someClass`, but instead pass `this` and access `number` using `this`. The issue with that is again, if I have multiple classes each needing to access a different variable from `fn1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way for `nestedNum` to change when `number` changes is to let `nestedNum` read from `number`.
Dart does not allow references or pointers to variables to be passed around. What you can do is to pass a function to `SomeClass` which provides the value each time it's needed.

```dart
void fn1() {
  int number = 5;
  SomeClass someClass = SomeClass(() => number);
  // Do some other things which take a long time
  number = 2;
  someClass.printer(); // prints 2!
}

class SomeClass {
  final int Function() _nestedNum;
  int get nestedNum => _nestedNum();

  SomeClass(int Function() nestedNum) : _nestedNum = nestedNum {
    printer();
  }

  void printer() {
    print(nestedNum);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! What's this part for `: _nestedNum = nestedNum` right after the constructor declaration?

Comment: That just stores the `nestedNum` parameter in the `_nestedNum` field. You could do `SomeClass(this._nestedNum);` instead, but I just prefer to not have parameters with private names, not even positional ones.